# How to render new page with react-router-dom in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating an application where I am getting a parameter from a function and if the parameter equals true I would render a new route instead.
I know how to use react-router-dom as to render new routes you would use something like this

```
<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

But I don't know how to call it in a function.

```
function functionName(success){
if (success){
//What do I write here?
// Something like go to path="/login"
}
}
```

Thank you

(edit)

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../../Context Api/authenticationAPI";
import { FaUserPlus } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Alerts from "./Alerts";
const Register = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { addUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const data = useContext(AuthContext).data;
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success) {
      history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div className="row mt-5">
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body">
          <h1 className="text-center mb-3">
            <i>
              <FaUserPlus />
            </i>{" "}
            Register
          </h1>
          <Alerts />
          <form>
            <div className="mb-2">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                type="name"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-2">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-2">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Create Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addUser({ name, email, password });
              }}
              className="btn btn-primary col-12"
            >
              Register
            </button>
            <p className="lead mt-4">
              Have An Account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaSignInAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row mt-5">
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body">
          <h1 className="text-center mb-3">
            <i>
              <FaSignInAlt />
            </i>{" "}
            Login
          </h1>
          <div className="mb-2">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Email"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-2">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              name="password"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
            />
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary col-12">Login</button>
          <p className="lead mt-4">
            No Account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the history object and programmatically navigate using history.push()

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory(); 

function functionName(success){
if (success) {
  history.push('/login')   
}
}
```

**Reference**

[useHistory Hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Thanks it works except the fact that in my login component I have a Link element which goes to a different page but now since I used history.push("/login") it doesn't work. Is there a way to stop the hook so normal <Link to="/register"></Link> would work

Comment: I am not clear with your question here .  " to stop the hook" which hook are you referring to ? .  which route you want to go when your if condition passes ?

Comment: What I am trying to say is after the useHistory hook is used, when I use press on the <Link to="/register"> in my login component it doesn't work because of the useHistory hook.

Comment: Add the complete code of your Login Component and also the component where you are using the `useHistory` hook .